# How to call base class method instead of extended class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In the following example, how can I directly call `Base.foo()` from `Base.bar()`, I understand why it's calling `Test.foo()` first, but is there any way to prevent this.

```
class Base {
   constructor() {
      console.log('Base constructor')
   }

   foo() {
      console.log('Base foo')
   }

   bar() {
     console.log('Base bar')

     this.foo();
  }
}

class Test extends Base {
  foo() {
    console.log('Test foo');

    super.foo();
  }
  bar() {
    console.log('Test bar');

    super.bar();
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.bar();
```

Output would be:

```
Base constructor
Test bar
Base bar
Test foo
Base foo
```

My expected output would be:

```
Base constructor
Test bar
Base bar
Base foo
```

Comment: In other words, you don't want to actually call the instance's `foo` method, but explicitly `Bar.prototype.foo`. Then that's exactly what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard JavaScript features while using ES2015 classes. In this case, simply use `Function.prototype.call()`:

```js
'use strict'
class Base {
   constructor() {
      console.log('Base constructor')
   }

   foo() {
      console.log('Base foo')
   }

   bar() {
     console.log('Base bar')

     Base.prototype.foo.call(this);
  }
}

class Test extends Base {
  foo() {
    console.log('Test foo');

    super.foo();
  }
  bar() {
    console.log('Test bar');

    super.bar();
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.bar();
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I see the code it makes a lot of sense.